# ConstraintLayout with 2 x 2 circles

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I want to draw 4 circles using constraintlayout with 2 rows, each row with 2 circles with 10dp margin between each of them. The fragment is placed in a viewpager under coordinatorlayout. This is the xml of the fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="@dimen/margin_medium"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

      <View
          android:id="@+id/summary_circle_1"
          android:background="@drawable/shape_circle_shadow"
          android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
          android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="0dp"
          local:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
          local:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:1"
          local:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
          local:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
          local:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/summary_circle_2"
            />
      <View
          android:id="@+id/summary_circle_2"
          android:background="@drawable/shape_circle_shadow"
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="0dp"
          local:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
          local:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:1"
          local:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
          local:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/summary_circle_1"
          local:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            />
      <View
          android:id="@+id/summary_circle_3"
          android:background="@drawable/shape_circle_shadow"
          android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="0dp"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          local:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:1"
          local:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/summary_circle_1"
          local:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
          local:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/summary_circle_4"
            />
       <View
          android:id="@+id/summary_circle_4"
          android:background="@drawable/shape_circle_shadow"
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="0dp"
          local:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
          local:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:1"
          local:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/summary_circle_3"
          local:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/summary_circle_3"
          local:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            />         


      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/summary_text_1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:text="text1"
        local:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        local:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        local:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/summary_text_2"
        />

      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/summary_text_2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="text2"
        local:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        local:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/summary_text_1"
        local:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        />

      <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="text3"
        local:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/summary_text_1"
        local:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        />



    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Unlike doing similar effect with textviews, circles space cannot be distributed no matter I used layout_weight or layout_constraintHorizontal_weight. If I fixed the size of the second circle, the first circle will take the rest of space available. Once I specified both width of 0dp to match constraints, the first one took all and the second one disappeared.

On the first row, I got only one circle with full screen width, while the second row with a half circle with full screen width & a tiny circle. Margins are gone too.

[image]

Another issue is that the fragment cannot be scroll. That's why I got only half circle on the second row.

How could I make this show as a 2 x 2 equal size circles using constraintlayout that can be scrolled?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It may help

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/summary_circle_1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@drawable/shape_circle_shadow"
            local:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/summary_circle_3"
            local:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/summary_circle_2"
            local:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            local:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            local:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/summary_circle_2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@drawable/shape_circle_shadow"
            local:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/summary_circle_4"
            local:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            local:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            local:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/summary_circle_1"
            local:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/summary_circle_3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@drawable/shape_circle_shadow"
            local:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            local:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/summary_circle_4"
            local:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            local:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            local:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/summary_circle_1" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/summary_circle_4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@drawable/shape_circle_shadow"
            local:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            local:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            local:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            local:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/summary_circle_3"
            local:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/summary_circle_2" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/summary_text_1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="text1"
            local:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            local:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/summary_text_2"
            local:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/summary_text_2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="text2"
            local:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/summary_text_1"
            local:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            local:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="text3"
            local:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            local:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/summary_text_1" />


    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```